# Why is Math.round in javascript slower than a custom built function?

Tags: javascript

I was messing around with creating a custom rounding function that could round to whatever interval I wanted. eg(if I was working with degrees it would round to the nearest 15 degrees)  Anyways I decided to see how fast it was compared to Math.round and come to find out it is slower.  I am using firebug on FF8

```
function R1(a,b){var c=a%b;return a-c+(c/b+1.5>>1)*b}

function R2(a){return Math.round(a)}

var i,e=1e5;
console.time('1');
i=e;
while(i--){
  R1(3.5,1);
}
console.timeEnd('1');
console.time('2');
i=e;
while(i--){
  R2(3.5);
}
console.timeEnd('2');
```

and my results were

```
1: 464ms
2: 611ms
```

I ran them several times in different ways, but always R1 came out faster.  Maybe this is just a FF thing, but if so what is causing it.

**EDIT:**
I took each out of the function call to see what would happen

```
var i,e=1e5,c;
console.time('1');
i=e;
while(i--){
  c=3.5%1;
  3.5-c+(c/1+1.5>>1)*1;
}
console.timeEnd('1');
console.time('2');
i=e;
while(i--){
  Math.round(3.5);
}
console.timeEnd('2');
```

and the times I'm getting

```
1: 654ms
2: 349ms
```

Comment: Consider posting a http://jsperf.com test-case. Sometimes different browsers/versions can act entirely differently, so what you are seeing might not be what everyone else sees :)

Comment: My results: `1: 190ms 2: 102ms`. Chrome on Windows.

Comment: @pst the link says the site is for sale.

Comment: Yeah, I messed up :( -- fixed now.

Comment: Does anything change if you say `var R2 = Math.round` instead of wrapping `Math.round` in another function? That seems to speed it up for me (Safari on OS X), although in my case R2 was already faster.

Comment: In Safari I get 6ms and 3ms, so Math.round is twice as fast.

Comment: Here is the jsperf test-case: http://jsperf.com/comparing-custom-and-bult-in-math-round . `Math.round` was moved outside `R2` as *Kevin* recommended.

Comment: They're both running at about 200 ms for me in those tests. Yours seems to take about 10ms longer on average (but sometimes it's faster). Chromium 14.

Comment: @KevinBallard I did what you suggested and took R1 out of a function call as well.  And the scores favored the Math.round. I'll edit the question to show what I did.

Comment: Chrome 15.0.874.121, OS X, jsperf says homebrew rounding is 65% slower.

Comment: R2 is, of course, doing two calls vs one for R1.  But regardless of that, tests like this can be badly distorted by localized JITC behaviors that might be entirely different with slightly different code invoked in a slightly different order.

Comment: Is this still relevant today? We're at FF v68 now

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The short answer is that in Firefox 8 (but not 9), `Math.round` ends up calling a C++ function, which is slow in JITs. The long answer is that it's complicated, and it comes out different in different versions of Firefox. Also, because JITs are involved, it's going to be different on different processors and OSs.

A bit of background: According to ECMA-262, `Math.round` rounds to the nearest integer, except that for 0.5, it rounds toward +Inf, and for [-0.5, -0.0] it rounds to -0.0 (IEEE-754 negative zero). In order to get that right, `Math.round` has to do more than `R1`. It will need either to do some floating-point comparisons for the range that rounds to -0 (which V8 does), or copy the sign from the input (which SpiderMonkey does).

Now, for Firefox 8, both loops get compiled by the tracejit. For the loop with `R1`, `R1` gets inlined and compiled to pure native code. `R2` is inlined and compiled to call a C++ function called `js_math_round_impl` (in `js/src/jsmath.cpp`).

- Calling any function costs extra because the parameters need to be set up, a call made, registers pushed, etc.
- Calling `Math.round` or the like costs extra because the code needs to verify that Math.round is still the default `Math.round` (i.e., verify no monkeypatching).
- Calling a C++ function costs extra in JITs because the JIT doesn't know what registers the C++ function uses, so the compiled JS function has to store all caller-save registers before the call and reload them all afterward. The call may also clear out other assumptions, preventing other optimizations.
- And, as mentioned earlier, `Math.round` has to do more work than `R1`.

I tried a few different tests in JS and C to try to figure out whether the call is more important, or the -0 check. The results varied, but it looked like the call was generally the greater part of the slowdown (70-90% of it).

In Firefox 9, with JM+TI, `R1` and `R2` are about equally fast. In that case, `R1` again gets inlined (I think) and compiled to pure native code. For `R2`, `Math.round` is implemented by a piece of jitcode that handles positive numbers directly but calls a C++ function for negative numbers (and `NaN`, etc). So for the example given, both run in jitcode, and `R2` happens to be a bit faster.

In general, with functions like `Math.round` (something that traditionally has been a call to a C++ function, but is simple enough that at least some cases can be done directly in jitcode), the performance is going to depend a lot on how much jitcode optimization the engine implementers did for that particular function.

Comment: Just a note to readers - Dave is a JavaScript guru at Mozilla :).

Comment: @DaveMandelin Thanks for the detailed answer.  It is interesting to see all the things that come together to get something like this to work properly.  Also, maybe I'm misinterpreting these http://jsperf.com/comparing-custom-and-bult-in-math-round/2 results, but does ffb 11.01a then run R1 significantly slower than say FF8, but run Math.round a lot faster?

Answer (score 8):

The comparison is actually not correct. `R2()` is a function, that is calling `Math.round()`. `R1()` is doing rounding directly.

So `R2` includes extra function call - that is a slow operation.

Try to compare the rounding implementation with same conditions:

```
function R1(a,b){var c=a%b;return a-c+(c/b+1.5>>1)*b}
R2 = Math.round;
```

Credits goes to *Kevin Ballard* who suggested moving `Math.round()` out of `R2()`.

See: http://jsperf.com/comparing-custom-and-bult-in-math-round .

### Update:

Results for Firefox are very different than for Chrome.

*Note: I'm inexperienced in this area, so I'm guessing here. If anybody experienced can provide his take on this numbers, that would be awesome.*

It looks that Firefox is optimizing heavily when the input value is not changing. It can optimize `R1(3.5)` this way but optimizing `Math.round` is probably more difficult to optimize, because of dynamic nature of JavaScript. `Math.round` implementation can change at any point during the execution of the code. `R1()` is using only arithmetic and bitwise operations. The performance of functions using built-in `Math.round` (`R2()` and `R3()`) is on par with other browsers (except IE 9 :o) ).

Somebody had a great idea and created 2nd revision of the test-case:

http://jsperf.com/comparing-custom-and-bult-in-math-round/2 .

This revision is testing also performance of functions where the value passed to them is changing.

**Any idea why `Built-in Math.round` so performant compared even to custom rounding with static input?**

Comment: Yes, Firefox is strangely much better at the custom round.

Comment: What about a perf that also included `function R3 (a) { return Math.round(a) }` to compare with `R2` from case #1.

Comment: Firefox has slowly slipped into trash. Not so strange, I think.

Comment: @pst Good idea. It is in. Please retest :). The results from Firefox are very surprising. I will tweet mozilla guys, hopefully somebody will explain :).

Comment: @StefanKendall Maybe I'm reading the jsperf results wrong, but the Math.round in FF seems to be on par with the other browsers just the custom function seems to do really well.

Comment: @dzejkej If you could get an answer back from mozilla it would be interesting.  I'll give it a while and see if anyone else comes up with an answer if not you came the closest so I'll accept yours.

Comment: @qw3n I've updated my answer once again. The problem is that I don't feel my answer is actually answering that much - more and more questions are arising :P. I don't think this is currently ready to be closed. Good job! :)

Comment: @qw3n: The real performance (actual use of Math.round) is worse than that of Chrome, but it looks like the values for the wrapped functions are being memoized. That explains why the function wrap speeds up execution - execution stops happening.

I'm not sure how this can be done reliably in javascript, but it seems fishy. I have to imagine anyone looking for efficiency would have made this optimization manually; i.e: extracting constant operations out of tight inner loops, as games often do.

Comment: As an aside, I tried to modify the test using Math.random, and FF's Math.random is much, much faster than Chrome's implementation, as I'm guessing FF is trading randomness for speed.

So I couldn't get good data. :/

Comment: @dzejkej Definitely agree on the more questions than answers right now. Funny how I was just playing around and kind of out of nowhere I was like that makes no sense.  Anyways thanks for the work, maybe someone can dig up some more answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the exact source, but it was a Google tech talk video discussing this. A field that is part of an object (such as `this.field`) is slower than a direct reference, since the Javascript needs to go up the object chain to find the variable or function.

Edit: This probably isn't the case here.

Comment: Actually, any halfway reasonable implementation of Java takes zero time to "go up the scope chain".  Each class has a method table, and the method pointers from superclasses are copied down, so only one table needs to be consulted.  And `Math` is a class, and not a "member" of anything.

Comment: Hmm, I always figured everything was part of the window object.

Comment: @HotLicks We are talking about Java*script* here, not Java. JS doesn't have classes, it's a prototypal language.